# How to handle the staging app on the Google Developer Console?

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

I'm a person in charge of Android application operation.

Our team have the following two apps on one Google Play Developer Console.

These apps have same features excluding each datas.

- App A: Production app (public on the store)
- App B: Staging app connected to the database of staging server (unpublic on the store)
  ※App B is replicated from App A, so their features are completely same.

Please let me ask three questions below.

【1】
Is App B need to follow the google play policies?
Do I need to fix App B every time when google update their policy?

【2】
Originally App B is the same application as App A, then does it mean the violation of the following policy “Impersonation”?
https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9888374?hl=en&ref_topic=9969539

【3】
If there is a maintenance costs of【1】, and a risk of【2】, I think it would be better to request the deletion of the App B to goole play developer console.
In general, "staging app” as this case is, How should we handle?

Please give us your opinion.
Thank you.

Comment: How did you end up doing this?

Answer (score 1):

【1】Yes, Yes

【2】No, you own the first app too

【3】you could delete App B and start using [Firebase App Distribution](https://firebase.google.com/products/app-distribution) for staging, it is still in BETA but it is reliable. it is very quick to push new updates for all your testers.